# Changing activity from fragment, without creating new activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, fragment

I am making an app, where i have a menu bar at the top, which is a fragment, so i can just define one menu, and show it on all my other activities. problem is that i navigate between activities by:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.LOG");
  startActivity(intent);
```

this is a problem, as it then creates a new activity time, and doesnt just resume it if its already created. i have looked into doing it like this:

```
   Intent logpage = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, LogActivity.class);
   startActivity(logpage);
```

As far as i know that will make it so that it will automatically resume an activity if it has been created, but then i have to know where i am when pressing the button, and as far as i can tell the fragment cant know that. plus it isn't a real activity, which makes it a bigger problem. 
So how do i make it so that it automatically resumes my activities, and doesn't just constantly create new ones when i navigate the app?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

What about tabview and custom tabs? Did you considered this option? It will be easier to manage activities

Comment: i have taken a quick look at tabs, but it doesnt seem that straight forward to do. or is it just appearence? because it would look alot better with tabs.

Comment: I think it's easier than what you want. Check this link http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: i have tried that tutorial, but apparently the entire TabActivity that it extends has been deprecated. ive read somewhere in here that we are suppoed to use fragments and then style them to look like tabs, but is this really true? yes, that which you linked to was actually quite simple and easy, just a shame if its all gone :S

Comment: I didn't know it was deprecated. But there will be some examples of fragments. Check also this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html and api docs and developer resources

Comment: that is also deprecated, looks like we are gonna have to go with something like actionbars, but then we apparently have to change our activities to fragments, which is gonna be too much work.

Comment: So use simpliest solution. Use deprecated TabActivity. There are a lot of apps which use tabactivity.